# Onclick the + button, add fields

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, forms, button

when you click on the "+" button, regenerate all fields below the existing ones, with TypeScript. I tried to rely on pure javascript, with appendChild, but I didn't have much success.[image]

```
<div id="duplicate">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can change u div col-md-6 with col-md-12 then try again it's basic solution

Comment: I can't, because in the second col-md-6, there is content, I must duplicate the entire div with id "duplicate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cloneNode` to clone the existing `div` then insert it after the current div before the next sibling. The issue might be the fact that your element id's will be duplicated so you'll have to be careful if you're using the id's for something.

```js
var currentDiv = document.getElementById('duplicate');
var clonedDiv = currentDiv.cloneNode(true);
currentDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(clonedDiv, currentDiv.nextSibling);
```

```html
<div id="duplicate">
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Other question... If i needed make inversion ? Delete one div?